# Cannot invoke setText(String) on the array type

Tags: java, arrays, string, invoke

Hi i am having an issue with trying to getting an array from my server. I am gonna try to be as specific as i can. i hope this post wont be too long.

```
public static Appointment[] getAppointments(DateTime date, String titel, String note, Date startDate, Date endDate, String location) {
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
    Appointment[] appointments = new Appointment[1];
    CalendarDate calendarDate;

    appointments.setTitle(titel);
    appointments.setNote(note);
    appointments.setStartDate(startDate);
    appointments.setEndDate(endDate);
    appointments.setLocation(location);

    String gsonString = gson.toJson(date);
    String result = GetCalendar(gsonString);



    appointments = (Appointment[])gson.fromJson(result, Appointment[].class);

    return appointments;
}   

private static String GetCalendar(String jsonInput){

    String result = "Error";
    try {
        Socket clientSocket = new Socket("localhost", 8888);
        DataOutputStream outToServer = new DataOutputStream(
                clientSocket.getOutputStream());
        byte[] input = jsonInput.getBytes();
        byte key = (byte) 3.1470;
        byte[] encrypted = input;
        for (int i = 0; i < encrypted.length; i++)
            encrypted[i] = (byte) (encrypted[i] ^ key);

        System.out.println(encrypted);
        outToServer.write(encrypted);
        outToServer.flush();
        BufferedReader inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                clientSocket.getInputStream()));
        result = inFromServer.readLine();
        clientSocket.close();

    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return result;
}
```

It is supposed to receive data from this class, which is on the serverproject.

```
public class Events {
ArrayList<Calendar> events = new ArrayList<Calendar>();

public ArrayList<Calendar> getEvents() {
    QueryBuilder qb = new QueryBuilder();
    try {
        ResultSet rs = qb.selectFrom("calendar").all().ExecuteQuery();
        while (rs.next())
        {
            //String values from SQL database (must be created)
            int calendarID = rs.getInt("Calendarid");
            int createdby = rs.getInt("userid");
            Date startDate = rs.getDate("start");
            Date endDate = rs.getTime("end");
            String title = rs.getString("Title");
            String note = rs.getString("Note");
            String location = rs.getString("Location");

            int stringCalendarID = Integer.valueOf(calendarID);
            int stringCreatedby = Integer.valueOf(createdby);

            String stringTitle = String.valueOf(title);
            String stringNote = String.valueOf(note);
            String stringLocation = String.valueOf(location);



            //System.out.println(String.valueOf(startDate.getTime()));

            events.add(new Calendar(stringCalendarID, stringCreatedby, stringTitle, stringNote, stringLocation));               
        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return events;
}

public void setEvents(ArrayList<Calendar> calendar) {
    this.events = calendar;
}
```

however i get this error in all appointments

```
    appointments.setTitle(titel);
    appointments.setNote(note);
    appointments.setStartDate(startDate);
    appointments.setEndDate(endDate);
    appointments.setLocation(location);
```

Cannot invoke setTitle(String) on the array type Appointment[]

what am i doing wrong? 
I hope you can help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appointment[] creates an entirely new object type: an array of appointment objects. It no longer is just an appointment object and thus does not inherit the setTitle member.

You have to get an appointment object from the array and then invoke the setTitle function on it:

For example

```
Appointment a = appointments[who];
a.setTitle("whatever");
```

Or even more simply

```
(appointments[who]).setTitle("whatever");
```

"who" is an integer that represents the index of an item in the appointments array in both examples

Answer (score 0):

The array doesn't have the `setTitle` method, the `Appointment` does (I assume).

Perhaps you are looking for something like:

```
Appointment appointment = new Appointment();
appointment.setTitle(titlel);
//etc.
Appointment[] appointments = new Appointment[1];
appointments[0] = appointment;
```